# Interpolations for HTML DOM event attributes (Angular)

Tags: angularjs

Since Angular 1.2.10 (~ stable ~)

> Interpolations for HTML DOM event attributes are disallowed.  Please
>   use the ng- versions (such as ng-click instead of onclick) instead.

Ok new version and all, but then why this won't work ?

```
<img ng-repeat="tab in tabs" ng-src="tab.imgOff" ng-mouseover="this.src = tab.imgOn">
```

Is it this.src ? Anyone have the same problem (or a solution) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are trying to go around using angular.  The following should work:

```
   <img  ng-repeat="tab in tabs" ng-src="{{tab.tabImg}}" ng-init="tab.tabImg=tab.imgOff" ng-mouseover="tab.tabImg = tab.imgOn" ng-mouseout="tab.tabImg=tab.imgOff">
```

The `tab.tabImg` doesn't exist in the array but the init will add that attribute to the tab object and initialize it to the off state.  Then, on your mouse events you just set it to the appropriate values thus never having to deal with `this.src` which you probably shouldn't manipulate (outside of a directive) in the first place.

Here is a demo:

http://plnkr.co/edit/s4wtB6zIfF7EGabbQgzf?p=preview

Alternatively you can accomplish the same thing with a flag which doesn't need an init:

```
 <img  ng-repeat="tab in tabs" ng-src="{{tab.isHover? tab.imgOn : tab.imgOff}}" 
    ng-mouseover="tab.isHover=true" 
   ng-mouseout="tab.isHover=false">
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/GvVKxiFBoN6ALNjNJjp0?p=preview

To answer about `this.src` you might want to check out the source code for the directive.  I'd bet that `this` is referencing the directive linking function and not the element which means it won't do what you think it will do.

Comment: Thanks, the 'alternatively' was exactly what I was searching for.
Now I don't have to put a ternary in ng-mouseout in case tab.active
Also thanks for explaining this.src